# C# Parse list of git commits using json.net

Tags: c#, json, github, json.net, github-api

I've been browsing various websites and the JSON.net docs but I can't find an elegant way to do this.

### The Problem

I have to parse a list of GitHub commits since a certain date.

The example json file I've been using for testing: [example json file](https://api.github.com/repos/QuiZr/ProjectPorcupineLocalization/commits?since=2016-10-25T04:15:52Z&sha=Someone_will_come_up_with_a_proper_naming_scheme_later)

The json is just a large (or empty) array. The problem is I don't need all of the data, I just need the sha of each commit.
However, if you look at each type in the array, there are multiple shas.

There is the base sha:

```
"sha": "fde139ae1d8fcf82bb145bbc99ed41763202e28f",
```

the tree sha:

```
"tree": {
        "sha": "5d33d345f2df166bc4c56cc9307a61a5ee57d346",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/QuiZr/ProjectPorcupineLocalization/git/trees/5d33d345f2df166bc4c56cc9307a61a5ee57d346"
      },
```

and the parent sha(s):

```
"parents": [
      {
        "sha": "8b9b43e813645c3a66911247b3dca916af937738",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/QuiZr/ProjectPorcupineLocalization/commits/8b9b43e813645c3a66911247b3dca916af937738",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/QuiZr/ProjectPorcupineLocalization/commit/8b9b43e813645c3a66911247b3dca916af937738"
      }
    ]
```

I only want the first sha. not the other shas.

### Requirements

- Needs to use JSON.net (not Ockokit)
- Should be elegant
- Needs to support the Unity game engine (i.e. C# version less than or equal to 2.0)
- I really don't want to create a new object type just for this.

Comment: Unity... the Game Engine? I don't think it supports C# *only* up to v. 2.0.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ According this post here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/924021/what-is-the-version-of-net-in-unity-5.html It is .NET 2.0 I think that is the same as C# version 2?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ: Well no, it supports C# the *language* a lot later than that, but currently only supports the CLR v2.0, and .NET framework up to 3.5 I believe (with some missing aspects). But Json.NET supports .NET 2.0, I think... at least, there are versions that do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I've already got Json.NET setup using Unity and it works fine.

Comment: Right. But you should be able to use C# 3 language features such as anonymous types without any problems, for example. Now, *why* don't you want to create a new type for this? That's one of the simplest ways to get Json.NET working - just create a type matching the JSON, and deserialize to it. If you don't want to do that, you can use LINQ to JSON with `JObject.Parse` - have you tried that? It's always worth explaining unusual requirements and showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Ah, OK. Good to know @JonSkeet . I will keep that in mind.

Comment: You may not have seen, but I added quite a bit to my comment asking for more details about what you've tried and why you don't want a new type...

Comment: @JonSkeet Because it is an insignificant part of the codebase that doesn't IMO deserve an entire new type.

Comment: If you really do not want new type, you can deserialize it using anonymous types. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm

Comment: @hcorion: Even if that were the simplest way to do it? You could make it a nested class, and no other code would need to care. That does seem a very strange requirement if it's blocking your progress.

Comment: @Mats391 That is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll start fiddling with this, but it would be cool if you created a formal answer so you could get the credit.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use LINQ to JSON very easily in this case - parse the text as a `JArray`, then ask for the `sha` property of each object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
        List<string> hashes = array.Select(o => (string) o["sha"]).ToList();
        foreach (var hash in hashes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(hash);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this uses lambda expressions which are from C# 3, but that should be fine in Unity - it only supports the *CLR* v2, but the .NET 3.5 framework, I believe.

In future though, I wouldn't let concerns such as "It's only a small part of the codebase" put you off creating a type - if LINQ to JSON didn't exist, creating a model type for the commit and deserializing to that would be a perfectly good solution.

Comment: Awesome, Works like a charm. I also didn't realize nested classes were a thing. Just a quick question, why var in the foreach? Why not string?

Comment: @hcorion `var` is just a shorthand for the type (in this case `string`). It's just shorter (and you don't have to change it should the type of `hashes` ever change).

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want new type, you can deserialize it using anonymous types. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm